# dirac delta function limit form equality

Tags: real-analysis, limits, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

Show that
$$\lim_{y\to\infty}\frac{1}{\pi}\frac{y}{y^2+x^2} = \delta(x)$$

I do not know where the $\pi$ arise.

Comment: I don't know either shouldn't that limit always equal to 0?

Comment: @frank000: The limit is not to be taken pointwise, but in the usual topology on the space of [distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_%28mathematics%29).

Comment: Hint: what do you get if you integrate the function on the right side over $\mathbb{R}$ (essentially pairing it, as a distribution, with the function 1)?  What do you get if you leave out the $\pi$?

Answer (score 3):

The constant $\pi$ is to normalize the area under the curve to unity.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\frac{y}{y^2+x^2}}dx = \pi$$